# Send back FullCalendar events to .NET with AJAX

Tags: asp.net-core, fullcalendar-5

I would like to sendback FullCalendar events to .NET with an AJAX request. I create a custom button for that :

```
    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Planning visites";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div id='calendar'></div>

@section scripts
{
<script>

    let date = new Date();
    let month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    let day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    
    let dateDuJour = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    let dateDuJourplusunan = (year + 1) + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        //themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',

        //plugins: [ timeGridPlugin ],
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        selectable: true,
        selectOverlap: false,
        //selectMirror: true,
        
        validRange: {
        start: dateDuJour,
        end: dateDuJourplusunan
        },
        
        customButtons: {
            enregistrermodifs: {
                text: 'enregistrer',
                click: function() {
                    var eventsobj = calendar.getEvents();
                    var data = JSON.stringify(eventsobj);
                    //var data = JSON.serialize(eventsobj);
                    alert(data);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("MAJAgenda","Agenda")',
                        //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', // when we use .serialize() this generates the data in query string format. this needs the default contentType (default content type is: contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8') so it is optional, you can remove it
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: data,
                        success: function(result) {
                            alert('Successfully received Data ');
                            console.log(result);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('Erreur : enregistrement non effectué');
                            console.log('Failed');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        
        
        
        headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next,today,enregistrermodifs',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,dayGridDay'
        },
      
        buttonText: {
        today:    'Aujourdhui',
        month:    'mois',
        week:     'semaine',
        timeGridWeek: 'jour',
        day:      'jour',
        list:     'liste'
        },
      
        initialDate: dateDuJour,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      
        events:'@Url.Action("RecupDonneesAgenda","Agenda")?annonceId=@ViewBag.AnnonceId',

        select: function(info) {
            calendar.addEvent({
                //id:     info.startStr,
                title: 'Indisponibilité',
                start: info.startStr,
                end:   info.endStr,
                allDay: false
              });
        },
        
       eventClick: function(info) {
           var eventobj = info.event;
           eventobj.remove();
        }
    });

    calendar.render();
    calendar.setOption('locale', 'fr');
    });

</script>
}
```

Here's my model in .NET :

```
public class AgendaAJAX
{
    public string? title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? end { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my action method :

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MAJAgenda(AgendaAJAX? agenda)
    {
        string userID = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        ////List<Agenda> agenda = await _context.Agendas.Where(a => a.AnnonceID == annonceId && a.Personne1 == userID).ToListAsync();

        //JsonResult result = new JsonResult(agenda);

        return View("Agenda");
    }
```

THE AJAX call works well : here's the JSON data :

[{"title":"Indisponibilité","start":"2022-06-09T07:30:00+02:00","end":"2022-06-09T12:30:00+02:00"},{"title":"Indisponibilité","start":"2022-06-10T10:00:00+02:00","end":"2022-06-10T15:00:00+02:00"},{"title":"Indisponibilité","start":"2022-06-11T07:00:00+02:00","end":"2022-06-11T09:30:00+02:00"}]

The problem is that I don't receive any data in the action method : agenda remains null.

I don't understand why.

If you can help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have this " alert('Successfully received Data ');"?

Comment: Can you share more code about your view? So that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have the message 'Successfully received Data'

Comment: Here's the full chtml page code :

Comment: You send a collection but expect a single AgendaAJAX item. Change `AgendaAJAX? agenda` to `List<AgendaAJAX>? agendas` in your controller.

Comment: I found the solution : I needed to write MAJAgenda([FromBody]List<AgendaAJAX>? agenda) instead of MAJAgenda(AgendaAJAX? agenda). Thanks guys for your answers !